# About the versions of Google Colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

What is the version of the following libraries in Google Colaboratory on 2022/11/2?

Python
Pytorch
Numpy

I don't see it listed and I'm confused.

Comment: I'm sorry.
Can you also tell me the version of Matplotlib as of 2022/11/2?